# How to prevent mysql injection in Php before it is submitted to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Recently, I got my database wiped through a hacker inserting a `DROP table` command through a signup form.

This annoyed me and got me thinking:

How can I prevent mysql injection in php, **before** the information is sent to the database, e.g is there a way to detect that the user is trying to inject bad code into the database that can wipe it, and if so, detect it and display an error?

Also, is there a way to detect the mysql injection **after** it has been added, so when I am displaying the query, if it is the delete injection code, don't display it.

Thanks again, I apologise for any waffle.

Comment: You use prepared/parameterized statements. Then injections simply aren't possible (because all user input goes through the bound parameters, and the database knows its not a SQL command)

Comment: I'd search for a question before you post it.  There are many SQL injection prevention questions already.  Not scolding just letting you know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: What function you are using to run your queries at the moment?

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with the binding syntax.  This alone will prevent most injection attacks.

Example:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
                'UPDATE users ' .
                'SET userEmail=:email, userSalt=:salt, userPass=:pass ' .
                'WHERE userId=:userId LIMIT 1' );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':email',  $this->_email,    \PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':salt',   $this->_salt,     \PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':pass',   $this->_password, \PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':userId', $this->_id,       \PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $stmt->execute();
```

In the above example, trying to escape the `:email` binding to insert a `DROP TABLE` won't work.

You still need to be careful with user-provided data.  For instance, if the user provides a `$docId` for a `get document` query, make sure they're authorized for the document being requested.  (And not just guessing a `$docId` belonging to some other user).

Comment: +1 for resisting the urge to mention Bobby Tables :)

Comment: Agreed, and I'd recommend PDO, simpler + portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use PDO or mysqli I would suggest using transactions and only commiting to the database when you are **sure** that everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO or mysqli's bind parameters functionality:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

The PDO syntax is easier to use, but either will work:

```
$pdo = new PDO($stuff);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :baz');
$stmt->bindParam(':baz', $baz);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function hashPassword($str)
{
        return hash("sha512", $str . "salt");
        //Change so it fits your database configuration.
}

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = hashPassword($_POST['password']);

?>
```

This should do it.

Comment: Just one question, what does mysql_real_escape_string actually do?

Comment: @HBellamy, it escapes certain characters and is strongly advised to be used whenever you send data to a database. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: That grave delusion again. When it will be wiped from this site?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel An elaboration would be nice.

Comment: `$fieldname = "user;drop table users"; $fieldname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fieldname']); $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $fieldname";` enough?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to detect that the user is trying to inject bad code?

It is useless and wrong approach.
You have to format your data properly, not hunt for some odd codes.

Besides that, I have a feeling that your problem cannot be solved with prepared statements.
If so, you will find the solution in my answer in the question linked in the comments.